# Algorithm to generate the number of tuples that satisfy the sum equals product problem.

Tags: algorithms

**Problem Statement:** 
Let $n\geq 2$ be a natural number. We are interested in sequences $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ of natural numbers such that 
$$x_1+x_2+...+x_n = x_1x_2...x_n\text{ and }x_1\leq x_2\leq...\leq x_n.$$
Let $A(n)$ denote the set of all such sequences. Moreover, we denote by $a(n)$ the cardinality of the set $A(n).$  The goal is to generate $a(n)$ for $n\geq 2.$

**Attempt:** Naive attempt in Python 3.5

```
from itertools import product

def prod(tup):
    """
    Computes the product of all elements in the tuple. 
    """
    p = 1
    for i in tup:
        p = p*i
    return p

def a(n):
    """
    Check Sum Equals Product Property.
    """
    list_of_tuples = list(product(range(1,2*n+1), repeat = n))
    count = 0
    for tup in list_of_tuples:
        if sum(tup) == prod(tup):
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

It can be proved that for all $n\geq 3$ that 
$$x_1+x_2+...+x_n\leq 2n.$$ 
So I just used the bound $1\leq x_i\leq 2n$ for all $i=1,2,...,n.$ I know this is really bad because it is $O((2n)^n)$ and I not generating non-decreasing sequences. I guess one would want to reduce the number of tuples to check, but I am not sure how to do this. Perhaps someone has an idea?

Comment: Your code doesn't take into account the fact that $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \cdots \leq x_n$.

Comment: For $n \leq 10^4$, you can use the table on OEIS: https://oeis.org/A033178.

Answer (score 2):

One simple optimization you can use is as follows: since $x_1 + \cdots + x_n \leq 2n$, it follows that at most $\log_3 (2n)$ values are at least 3. You can go over all possible values for these $O(\log n)$ elements, and for each of them it should be easy to determine whether they can be completed (by adding only 1s and 2s) to a solution.

Taking this one step further, you can start adding elements to the sequence, from $x_n$ down, keeping track of the current product. If it exceeds $2n$, you can immediately halt.

You can probably optimize this much further, but this is already a good start.

Alternatively, OEIS has your sequence as [A033178](https://oeis.org/A033178), and a table for $n \leq 10000$.